# Django DeleteView success_url to previous/different page

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I have these url patterns:

```
app_name = "posts"
urlpatterns = [
    path('global/', PostListView.as_view(), name='global-list'),
    path('personal/', PersonalPostListView.as_view(), name='personal-list'),
    path('<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete'),
]
```

Inside each of the templates of PostListView, PersonalPostListView, and PostDetailView is a delete option like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'posts:delete' object.id %}">Delete</a>
```

What I want to happen is after deleting the object, it will redirect to the last page where the delete link was clicked (except for detail view). Thus, there are 3 possible cases as follows:

1. Case 1: PostListView template -> click delete -> PostDeleteView confirm delete template -> back to PostListView template
2. Case 2: PersonalPostListView template -> click delete -> PostDeleteView confirm delete template -> back to PersonalPostListView template
3. Case 3 (*the exception*): PostDetailView template -> click delete -> PostDeleteView confirm delete template -> back to PostListView template

Additionally, PostListView and PersonalPostListView are paginated and the PostDeleteView should return to the page from where the post is deleted.

This is my attempt so far:

```
class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post

    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
```

However, clicking delete from the PostListView returns `posts/15/delete/` which should just be `posts/global/`. Moreover, it should return `posts/personal/` if deleted from PersonalPostListView template and (*the exception*) `posts/global/` if deleted from PostDetailView template.

An alternative I've thought is to assign different DeleteViews (with different success_url) for each template. However, this seems to cause some redundancy in code when only the success_url should differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest OP to use different path configuration in `urls.py`,

```
path('global/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete-global'),
path('personal/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete-personal'),
```

Then in OPs view redirect depending on the url

```
class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post
    
   def get_success_url(self):
        if 'global' in self.request.path:
            return reverse_lazy('posts:global-list')
        else:
            return reverse_lazy('posts:personal-list')
```

Then adjust the `<a href="{% url ...` accordingly.

Comment: Your urls.py was my alternative and what I implemented at the moment. As for my views, I created more classes that inherits from the PostDeleteView but with different get_success_url (not really pleasing to look at). I like your get_success_url method, will most probably take it into consideration. For the meantime, I'll wait for other's response. Thank you for this!

Comment: Do you think it's possible to include the current page ```?page=...``` in get_success_url? When I printed out self.requests.path, it returned /posts/personal/35/delete. Or is this better implemented with function-based views?

Comment: Assuming you want to pass the page number from the template, then you can adjust the URL to include an optional parameter with the page number and adjust `get_success_url()` accordingly.